# Strange behavior from Tailwind blur class

Tags: reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

### **Problems**

So, today I was migrating from Chrome to Edge (I don't know if this was causing my issue). I encountered some issues while working on my project. The behavior of the tailwind `blur` class won't be rendered on Chrome and Edge. Strangely, the `blur` is rendered on Firefox. The rest of the classes are working fine without any issues. But the only problem is in the `blur` class.

### **What have I tried?**

- Looking up the same problem on the internet but haven't found one.
- Re-creating a new project and blurring some images, it works on all the browsers I have.
- Re-clone the project, but still won't solve my issue.

### **Details**

- Next.js TypeScript v13 (v13.2.1) with experimental app directory feature
- Using `yarn` package manager
- Using tailwind's latest version v3.2.7
- Using Edge
- Using turbopack

### **Expected behavior**

I'm expecting the background to be blurred.

You can found the expected result image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbrJK.png)

### **Unexpected behavior**

But I get the result like that. The image won't get blurred.

You can found the unexpected result image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3atg.png)

Note: Sorry I cannot post an image since Stackoverflow won't allow posting an image if you don't meet the minimum reputations.

Here is my root `page.tsx` in `src/app`

```
"use client"

import Image from "next/image"
import Button from "@/component/ui/Button"
import Blob from "@/component/blob/Blob"
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Badge from "@/component/ui/Badge"
import { GithubCircle, Instagram, ArrowRight } from "iconoir-react"
import Link from "next/link"

const Home = () => {
    const [isContentVisible, setIsContentVisible] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            setIsContentVisible(true)
        }, 500)

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <main className="flex flex-col justify-between min-h-screen p-8 mx-auto bg-black max-w-7xl min-w-screen md:min-w-3xl">
            <header
                className={`flex flex-row justify-between h-10 items-center bg-transparent z-10 opacity-0 transform -translate-y-full transition-all duration-1000 ${
                    isContentVisible ? "opacity-100 translate-y-0" : ""
                }`}
            >
                <Image
                    src="/logo.svg"
                    alt="logo Logo"
                    width={96}
                    height={18}
                    priority
                />
                <div className="flex flex-row space-x-4">
                    <Link href="/auth/login">
                        <Button intent="default">
                            <span className="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
                                Log in
                                <ArrowRight className="transition ease-in-out hover:translate-x-1" />
                            </span>
                        </Button>
                    </Link>
                    <Button intent="subtle">
                        <span>Join waitlist</span>
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </header>
            <section
                className={`flex flex-row items-center justify-between opacity-0 transform transition-all duration-[3000ms] ${
                    isContentVisible ? "opacity-100" : ""
                }`}
            >
                <div className="absolute z-10">
                    <Image
                        src="abstract.svg"
                        alt="abstract"
                        width={544.63}
                        height={136.5}
                        className="blur-2xl"
                        priority
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="z-20 flex flex-col max-w-xl gap-3">
                    <div>
                        <Badge intent="warning" text="Currently in development" />
                    </div>
                    <h1 className="inline-block font-bold leading-none text-transparent text-7xl bg-gradient-to-br from-white to-zinc-800 bg-clip-text md:text-6xl sm:text-5xl">
                        Reclaim your wasted hour
                    </h1>
                    <p className="text-base font-normal leading-6 text-grayDark-11">
                        Take your productivity to the next level with advanced tools
                        designed to help you streamline your work, maximize your time, and
                        accomplish more than ever before.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="h-[40rem] w-[48rem] transform-gpu lg:block hidden">
                    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0.0, 1.0, 9.0] }}>
                        <Blob />
                    </Canvas>
                </div>
            </section>
            <footer
                className={`opacity-0 transform translate-y-full transition-all duration-1000 ${
                    isContentVisible ? "opacity-100 translate-y-0" : ""
                }`}
            >
                <div className="flex flex-row items-center gap-6">
                    <Link
                        href="https://github.com/my-brand/logo"
                        target="_blank"
                        className="transition duration-200 ease-in-out bg-clip-text text-grayDark-10 hover:text-whiteA-12"
                    >
                        <GithubCircle strokeWidth={1} width="1.5rem" height="1.5rem" />
                    </Link>
                    <Link
                        href="https://instagram.com/my-brand"
                        target="_blank"
                        className="transition duration-200 ease-in-out bg-clip-text text-grayDark-10 hover:text-whiteA-12"
                    >
                        <Instagram strokeWidth={1} width="1.5rem" height="1.5rem" />
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Home
```

I tried looking up the same problem on the internet but haven't found one. I try creating a new project and blurring some images, it works on all the browsers I have.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: changing pixels to rem fixes the problem.

I have the same problem. And I was able to reproduce your behavior with a few more findings.

First my code:

From my react component:

```
<div className={`flex-1 flex ${styles.flexCenter} md:my-0 my-12 mr-12 relative`}>
    <Mate className='w-[50%] h-[auto] relative z-[5]' />
    <div className='absolute z-[0] w-[60%] h-[60%] top-12 yellow__gradient'/>
    <div className='absolute z-[1] w-[100%] h-[70%] rounded-full bottom-30 white__gradient'/>
    <div className='absolute z-[0] w-[50%] h-[50%] right-30 bottom-10 blue__gradient'/>
  </div>
```

From my CSS:

```
.yellow__gradient {
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(236, 206, 20, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 237, 21, 1) 100%);
      filter: blur(900px);
    }

.blue__gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(187, 165, 255, 0) 0%, #1083c0 100%);
  filter: blur(123px);
}

.white__gradient {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.507);
  filter: blur(750px);
}
```

Now, the strange (additional) thing that happened to me, was that the blue gradient did show in chrome/edge. Since the difference was in the blur amount, I've changed the value of the others, and found that it started showing below 210px blur.

Of course this is not a solution, since the blur is inconsistent between firefox, chrome/edge and safari (get to try it and behaves as chrome).

A possible workaround could be through JavaScript and a conditional using the navigator.userAgent property but it won´t fix the incognito thing. Perhaps a CSS expert finds this question and provides a better answer.

PS: can't be an extension. My edge is completely clean, without any extension (I barely use it) and has the same behavior.

Answer (score -1):

After I checked more and more, it seemed that some extensions I installed were causing the issues. So, when I run it on "normal" mode, the `blur` class, which will be generated into `--tw-blur: blur(40px);` are strike through. When I use incognito mode, which doesn't have any extensions installed, the classes aren't strike through. I wonder what extension is causing the issue.